# Finding it difficult to construct login functionalities. Bad request

Tags: python, reactjs, django, authentication

view.py

```
class Login(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request):        
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            username = serializer.data.get('username')
            password = serializer.data.get('password')          
            user = authenticate(password=password, username=username)

# This line above and below this comment
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return Response({"msg": "Login Successful"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response(
                    {
                        "errors": {
                            "non_field_errors": ["Email or Password is not valid"]
                        }
                    },
                    status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
                )
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)pe here
```

serializer.py

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

api.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://localhost:8000/',
}

)
```

signup

```
   const onSubmit = e =>{
        e.preventDefault()       
        api
            .post(`user/login/`,
                JSON.stringify({username, password}),
                )
           
            .then(({data}) =>{
                console.log(data)
            })
```

If if try to login on the browser, it returns
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

How to login from reactjs to django(python)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your serializer, in general, you should not use a `ModelSerializer` for the `User` model if it contains the `password`, instead just use a simple `Serializer`, also you can consider the `authentication` as part of the validation:

```py
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get('username')
        password = data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid credentials.')
        data['user'] = user  # include the user in validated_data
        return data
```

Now, you can use it in your view:

```py
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data.get('user')
        login(request, user)
        return Response({"msg": "Login Successful"})
```

Always try to avoid the if-else nightmare, in this case, we use the fact that `.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` will raise an exception if the validation fails, `APIView` will catch any `serializers.ValidationError` and return the corresponding response with a bad request header.